# Remove unwanted substring from a list of strings at specified indexes

Tags: python, string, list

New to python and I want to remove the prefix of two stings. Just leaving everything before the J and removing the .json.

I tried using [:1] but it removes the entire first string

```
name = ['190523-105238-J105150.json',
'190152-105568-J616293.json']
```

I want to output this

```
name = ['J105150',
'J616293']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split()` in a list-comprehension:

```
name = ['190523-105238-J105150.json',
'190152-105568-J616293.json']

print([x.rsplit('-', 1)[1].split('.')[0] for x in name])
# ['J105150', 'J616293']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `find()` function and array splicing.

```py
name = ['190523-105238-J105150.json' ,'190152-105568-J616293.json']
for i in range(len(name)):
    start_of_json = name[i].find('.json')
    start_of_name = name[i].find('J')
    name[i] = name[i][start_of_name:start_of_json]
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally the list is `name = ['190523-105238-J105150.json', '190152-105568-J616293.json']`.

`List comprehensions` in python are extremely useful and powerful.

`eq = [name[i][name[i].find("J"):name[i].rfind(".json")] for i in range(len(name))]`, a list comprehension is used to create a new list of values from the list `name` by finding the starting at the value `J` and going to `before` the `.json`. The result of `find()` is of type integer.

The complete code can be seen below.

```
def main():
    name = ['190523-105238-J105150.json', '190152-105568-J616293.json']
    eq = [name[i][name[i].find("J"):name[i].rfind(".json")] for i in range(len(name))]
    print(eq)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`output: ['J105150', 'J616293']`

Answer (score 0):

Doing [:1] will slice your current list to take only elements that are before index 1, so only element at index 0 will be present.
This is not what you want.
A regex can help you reach your goal.

```
import re
output = [re.search(r'-([\w+]).json', x).group(0) for x in your_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible approaches:

One is more verbose. The other does essentially the same thing but condenses it into a one-liner, if you will.

**Approach 1:**

In approach 1, we create an empty list to store the results temporarily.

From there we parse each item of `name` and `.split()` each item on the hyphens.

For each item, this will yield a list composed of three elements: `['190523', '105238', 'J105150.json']` for example.

We use the index `[-1]` to select just the last element and then `.replace()` the text `.json` with the empty string `''` effectively removing the `.json`.

We then append the item to the `new_names` list.

Lastly, we overwrite the variable label `name`, so that it points at the new list we generated.

```
name = ['190523-105238-J105150.json', '190152-105568-J616293.json']

new_names = []
for item in name:
    item = item.split('-')[-1]
    new_names.append(item.replace('.json', ''))
name = new_names
```

**Approach 2:**

```
name = ['190523-105238-J105150.json', '190152-105568-J616293.json']

name = [item.split('-')[-1].replace('.json', '') for item in name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it is not a data frame, it is an array.

You could use something simple as below line for this, assuming you have static structure.

```
name = [x[x.index("J"):x.index(".")] for x in name]
```